# How to submit a valid user request to Liferay Default Landing Page

Tags: liferay

```
I am using Liferay 6 .
```

I have created a page and added 6 portlets to it and configured inside portal-ext.properties file as
**auth.forward.by.last.path=true
default.landing.page.path=/user/test/home**

This private page with all my 6 portlets is  shown only  when i use Liferay's sign in Portlet (The default login page of Liferay )

Similarly i have my Custom Portlet  made of struts2 , which is shown on entering http:localhost:8086 as shown below

[image]

```
<s:form action="helloForm" method="POST" theme="simple">
    Enter Your Name:<s:textfield name="namer" />
    Enter Your Name:<s:textfield name="passer" />
    <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Currently , when user clicks on submit the Struts2 Action class recivies that as shown

```java
public String execute() throws Exception {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    String name = ParamUtil.getString(request, "namer");
    //  does Database check and decides the return page 
    return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;         
}
```

Now my requirement is that , if he is a valid user , i want to redirect him/her to the Landing Page configured

Please tell me how to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
HttpServletResponse response = ServletActionContext.getResponse();
String targetUrl = "/user/test/home";
response.sendRedirect(targetUrl);
```